# YouTube Chat Live streaming embed doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, embed, youtube-livestreaming-api

so for some reason this [Live Chat Embed](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9826490?hl=en#zippy=%2Cembed-live-chat) documentation no longer works when applied.

This used to work before, but now it is throwing this on the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=Lb3_VzuBDHI&embed_domain=<my domain>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

and the UI just shows:

```
www.youtube.com refused to connect.
```

As per the domain, I get the value via `window.location.host` so I'm pretty sure its correct.

The ID is also correct because whenever I open the same url on a new tab, it shows the chat for that specific stream.

I am also streaming (live) while testing this so the "chat gets destroyed once the live is over) doesn't apply.

Any Ideas? Is this function deprecated?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. The live chat url is returning the header X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN which means the iframe would only work on a youtube domain. Hard to tell if it's a bug or Youtube is now blocking the use of live chat.